# several files became root owned

Tags: 16.04

A lot of my files say the owner is root and I don't have access to them. These are files that I use on a daily basis. My Firefox isn't working either saying it's missing or inaccessible.

Comment: To change a file "thefile" to be your username (assuming your username is "me") you can enter the command `chown me thefile` which will change.ownership to you.  You need a `sudo` to elevate privileges if you aren't already owner so `sudo chown me thefile`.  If its a directory its the same, but you can add a -R to recursively do files underneath.  Or `sudo chown -R me /home/me/* ` to make you the owner of everything in your /home/me directory... Adjust this for your files...

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you have run a GUI program with `sudo`. This is one of the reasons why running a GUI program as `root` is discouraged.

To fix it (don't run this until you understand it):

```
sudo find $HOME -user root -exec chown $(id -u):$(id -g) {} +
```

This will find files and directories in `$HOME` that are owned by `root`, and change them to your `$UID` and `$GID`.

`man find; man id; man  chown ; man sudo` should get you started.